# Simple related rates derivative question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Rafael is walking away from a $12$-ft-tall lantern at a constant speed.
If the tip of Rafael's shadow is moving twice as fast as he walks, how tall is Rafael? I'm confused on the step where $dL/dt = 2dx/dt$. If we're looking at how fast the shadow is compared to his walk wouldn't we be comparing the derivative of s to the derivative of $x$ because $L$ is the whole distance including how much Raphael walked plus his shadow length?

[image]

[image]

Comment: To answer your question, it says "the tip of the shadow is moving twice as fast as he is walking"  Not that the shadow is growing twice as fast.  The tip of the shadow is at L.  So the speed of the tip is the speed the shadow is growing plus the speed he is walking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the comment of @turkeyhundt more explicit, the tip of the shadow has position $x+s=L$, so its rate of change with respect to time is: $\frac{d(x+s)}{dt}=\frac{dL}{dt}$. But it is given that this rate of change is twice that of Rafeal, so we have the relationship: $\frac{d(x+s)}{dt}=\frac{dL}{dt}= 2\frac{dx}{dt}$, since Rafael's rate of change is $\frac{dx}{dt}$. So that's where that comes from.

To find Rafeal's height, note that Rafeal's speed is constant, so we have $\frac{dx}{dt}=v$ for some constant $v$. So then Rafeal's position is $x(t)=vt +c_0$, where $c_0$ is his starting point. I assume Rafeal starts at $0$, i.e. at the lamp, though this isn't mentioned in the problem. Then we have $x(t)=vt$. Now $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{ds}{dt}$ so $s(t)=x(t)+c=vt+c$ for some constant $c$. $c=0$, since if Rafeal starts at $0$, at this time he casts no shadow as he is directly beneath the lamp, so we have $s(t)=x(t)$.By similar triangles: $\frac{12}{x+s}=\frac{h}{s}$, so $h=\frac{12s}{2s}=6$, so Rafeal is $6$ feet tall.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more on your second sentence: "But it is given that this rate of change is twice that of Rafeal, so we have the relationship: d(x+s)dt=2dxdt="?

Comment: I edited it. If that isn't clear let me know.